# How can I create an effective logic to create un-ordered multiple events into sequential event of order

Tags: java, json

I have following JSON file. This JSON file contains list of orders that came through during that day. There is original orders and also update orders that is referencing back to previous order listed in "previousOrderRef".

```
[
    {
        "orderNum":"1",
        "orderType":"Original",
        "orderContent":"Apple",
        "previousOrderRef":null
    },
    {
        "orderNum":"2",
        "orderType":"Original",
        "orderContent":"Pear",
        "previousOrderRef":null
    },
    {
        "orderNum":"3",
        "orderType":"Original",
        "orderContent":"Orange",
        "previousOrderRef":null
    },
    {
        "orderNum":"4",
        "orderType":"Original",
        "orderContent":"Apple",
        "previousOrderRef":null
    },
    {
        "orderNum":"5",
        "orderType":"Original",
        "orderContent":"Pear",
        "previousOrderRef":null
    }
    ,
    {
        "orderNum":"6",
        "orderType":"Updates",
        "orderContent":"Watermelon",
        "previousOrderRef":[2,4]
    },
    {
        "orderNum":"7",
        "orderType":"Updates",
        "orderContent":"Grapefruit",
        "previousOrderRef":[1,3]
    }
    ,
    {
        "orderNum":"8",
        "orderType":"Updates",
        "orderContent":"Grapes",
        "previousOrderRef":[5]
    }
    ,
    {
        "orderNum":"9",
        "orderType":"Updates",
        "orderContent":"Pear",
        "previousOrderRef":[7]
    },
    {
        "orderNum":"10",
        "orderType":"Updates",
        "orderContent":"Blood Orange",
        "previousOrderRef":[8]
    }
    ,
    {
        "orderNum":"11",
        "orderType":"Updates",
        "orderContent":"Blood Orange",
        "previousOrderRef":[9]
    }

]
```

This JSON file will be mapped to the following POJO using Jackson

```
public class MyOrder{
    private String orderNum;
    private String orderType;
    private String orderContent;
    private List<String> previousOrderRef;


    public String getOrderNum(){
        return orderNum;
    }

    public void setOrderNum(String orderNum){
        this.orderNum = orderNum;
    }

    public String getOrderType(){
        return orderType;
    }

    public void setOrderType(String orderType){
        this.orderType = orderType;
    }

    public String getOrderContent(){
        return orderContent;
    }

    public void setOrderContent(String orderContent){
        this.orderContent = orderContent;
    }

    public List<String> getPreviousOrderRef(){
        return previousOrderRef;
    }

    public void setPreviousOrderRef(List<String> previousOrderRef){
        this.previousOrderRef = previousOrderRef;
    }
}
```

In a separate file or output, I want to create some type of order audit where it shows the trail as chain of event shown below.

```
orderNum:1 -> orderNum:7 -> orderNum:9 -> orderNum:11
orderNum:2 -> orderNum:6 
orderNum:3 -> orderNum:7 -> orderNum:9 -> orderNum:11
orderNum:4 -> orderNum:6
orderNum:5 -> orderNum:8 -> orderNum:10
```

What would be the most effective way to create this type of chain?

Comment: so what have you tried so far to print it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, define an entity that can hold the required structure.

```
class MyOrderMapped{

    private String orderNum;
    private String orderType;
    private String orderContent;
    private List<MyOrderMapped> nextOrderRefs;

    public MyOrderMapped(String orderNum, String orderType, String orderContent) {
        this.orderNum = orderNum;
        this.orderType = orderType;
        this.orderContent = orderContent;
        this.nextOrderRefs= new LinkedList<>();
    }

    // getters and setters

}
```

Then, create a `Map` from `orderNum` to `MyOrderMapped`.

```
// orders is what you deserialize from JSON
List<MyOrder> orders = new LinkedList<>();
Map<String, MyOrderMapped> mappedById = orders
            .stream()
            .map(o -> new MyOrderMapped(o.getOrderNum(), 
                                        o.getOrderType(), 
                                        o.getOrderContent()))
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(MyOrderMapped::getOrderNum, Function.identity()));
```

Iterate your initial list and construct the order tree.

```
orders.stream().forEach(order -> {
        MyOrderMapped current = mappedById.get(order.getOrderNum());
        order.getPreviousOrderRef().forEach(parentOrderNum -> {
            MyOrderMapped parent = mappedById.get(parentOrderNum);
            parent.getNextOrderRefs().add(current);
        });
    });
```

Finally, you can get the order roots as follows.

```
Set<String> roots = orders
            .stream()
            .filter(value -> value.getPreviousOrderRef() == null || 
                             value.getPreviousOrderRef().isEmpty())
            .map(MyOrder::getOrderNum)
            .collect(Collectors.toSet());

List<MyOrderMapped> orderRoots = mappedById.values()
            .stream()
            .filter(current -> roots.contains(current.getOrderNum()))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```